# Check If Binary Tree Is Balanced

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

This is my wrong answer. I'm still confused about recursion, why can't I put true and false together instead of putting true at beginning?

```
public class Solution {
  public boolean isBalanced(TreeNode root) {    
    int left = findHeight(root.left);
    int right = findHeight(root.right);
    if (Math.abs(left-right) <= 1) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    } 
    return (isBalanced(root.left)&&isBalanced(root.right));

  }
  private int findHeight(TreeNode root) {  
    if (root == null) {
      return 0;
    }
    return Math.max(findHeight(root.left), findHeight(root.right)) + 1;
  }
}
```

This is the correct answer.

```
public boolean isBalanced(TreeNode root) {
    if (root==null) {
      return true;
    }
    int leftHeight = findHeight(root.left);
    int rightHeight = findHeight(root.right);
    if(Math.abs(leftHeight-rightHeight)>1) {
      return false;
    } 
    return isBalanced(root.left)&&isBalanced(root.right);
  }
```

Comment: `return (isBalanced(root.left)&&isBalanced(root.right));` will never have chance to execute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if (Math.abs(left-right) <= 1) { return true; } else { return false; }` will always `return` something, meaning you will never get to the recursive calls afterwards.